# How to understand why my app is entering an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs

I created a React app that does the following.

1. Load CSV.
2. Convert the CSV to JSON.
3. Convert the JSON to HTML Table.
4. On the button click do some processing.

Currently, my app is working as expected, but the issue is, it is going into an infinite loop on file load. I am not sure where I'm going wrong.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-danny-o2ck4h) is the working code. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please [edit] the post and add the code to the post, making it self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is going into an infinite loop on file load, because you put `csvArray` in `useEffect`'s array, this means: every time `csvArray` changed the function fired again.

The solution:

```
useEffect(() => {
   processCSV(csvData);
   if (isProcessChange) {
      setCsvArray(state => {
        state.map((item) => {
          var currRowValues = Object.entries(item);
          var nd = currRowValues.reduce((a, [key, value]) => {
            if (key === "sum") {
              return a;
            }
            return a + value;
          }, 0);
          return { ...item, sum: nd };
        });
      });
    }
  }, [isProcessChange, csvData]);
```

And put `setKeys` in separate `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
   setKeys(Object.keys(csvArray.length ? csvArray[0] : {}));
}, [csvArray]);
```

Demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-snowflake-y7ziqt

Comment: Thanks for this @Amr, when I Included your code, on button click, it gives me the error as `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')` at `      {csvArray.length >= 1 && (` you can look at the sandbox I linked in my question.

Comment: Demo of your app:
https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-snowflake-y7ziqt

Comment: Strange. I still see the error :-(

Comment: I got the solution, modified my use effect to   useEffect(() => {
    `if (readData) {
      processCSV(csvData);
      setReadData(false);
    }
    if (isProcessChange) {
      call();
      isProcessChange = false;
    }
  }, [isProcessChange]);` and added a new state `readData`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't thoroughly debugged your code, but it looks like you have an infinite loop in your `useEffect`. When you upload a file, that causes the `ProcessData` component to render, and that component has a `useEffect` which depends on `csvArray`. However, that same `useEffect` also modifies `csvArray`, which would cause it to run again. Generally, a `useEffect` hook should not change any state values it depends on.

Also, instead of just linking to your code, it's nice if the question itself includes a minimal code sample that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Apologies @Raphael, I didn't include the code as I wasn't sure of where the error is coming from. I'm pretty new to react, learning and trying out things.